# The type or namespace 'MapActivity' could not be found (using monodevelop for android)

Tags: android, monodevelop

i'm trying to do this tutorial here http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Maps_and_Location/Part_2_-_Maps_API and basically this is my code

```
namespace HelloM4A
{
    [Activity (Label = "HelloM4A")]
    public class Activity1 : MapActivity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.MapLayout);


        }

         protected override bool IsRouteDisplayed {
              get {
                      return false;              }
        }
    }
}
```

but I could not run it. It will give an error "The type or namespace 'MapActivity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

i can confirm that i've installed the Google APIs by Google Inc for all android platform (because it's being listed as installed in the android sdk manager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to choose the Google SDK? Did you? I mean that it is not enough to install it because it will not be available for all the platform but only for the "Google" version of them.

Comment: the problem is because i forgot to add using Android.GoogleMaps; and of course, i need to do as you answered too.. so thanks!